HTTP 400 Error on Logon Page After 20-30m with AntiForgeryToken
We implemented the ASP.NET Core AntiforgeryToken technology in our web application and that works for our Views and API calls.  While at the logon page of our application, waiting about 30 minutes and trying to logon will result in a HTTP 400 Bad request error.  If I remove the [AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken] attribute from the Account Controller, the bad request error will not happen.
From what I have read, we want to keep AntiforgeryToken behavior on the logon page to prevent CSRF attacks.  I am thinking that after 20-30 minutes, the server or IIS times out and its AntiforgeryToken value is removed.  If that is the case, the token on the server no longer matches the AntiforgeryToken value in the View of the logon page.
How do we account for this workflow?  I don't want to ping the server to keep it alive.  Redirecting to the logon page and requiring the user to logon twice is not clean.  I even tried making the AntiforgeryToken expiration to be days long, but that had no affect.
Note:  The logon page could be left open for days if the user walks away.
Account Controller:
[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
Views:
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
Ajax API Calls:
beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('XSRF-TOKEN', $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()); }
Startup.cs:
services.AddAntiforgery(options => {
options.HeaderName = 'XSRF-TOKEN';
});

Appreciate all suggestions and thank you for the help!

Actually, the anti token contains the its own lifetime, if the user need login in, they should go to the login page, it will re-generate the login page and the request will use the new token to access the page.

@BrandoZhang - the issue is that the user is already at the logon page and waits 30 or more minutes which results in the HTTP 400 Bad Request error.  One idea that I have is to create a Javascript timer on the logon page.  If the timer expires, redirect the user to an information page with a "logon" button.  Clicking the "logon" button would redirect back to the logon page for their credentials, but that just doesn't seem clean to me.

In IIS Manager you need to set "Idle Time-out (minutes)" for the application pool. (It's in advanced settings methinks)  The default is 20 minutes.

in general CSRF attacks would want to steal session.  Since you don't necessarily have a session before logging in (or at least it will change afterwards) anti-forgery isn't a big factor.  HOWEVER, it does prevent an obscure attack where the attacker tries to force a user to login as an attacker controlled account, and then retrieve info they entered as them later.

@browsermator - I get the IIS idle time out, but if I change it to a later time value, it will only delay the HTTP Error 400 (e.g., If I change IIS idle time to 40m, then the HTTP 400 Error would show up around 40m instead of the current 20m).  Know what I mean?  I would think that the ASP.NET Core would have a token sync for this type of issue.  I am also wondering how other sites handle this as we cannot be the first to encounter this.

the token is tied to the session.  If the session times out then the anti-forgery token is no longer valid.  The browser's cookie is a session cookie (that's purely the browser's session timeout... it's expired after the browser closes... so if you keep that open on the same page, it is never updated to the server session)

So after 40 minutes in your case, you would need to refresh the page or the anti-forgery token will be invalid.   It should also be noted that if you have a lot of traffic, it's better to have a smaller idle timeout.  Server-side sessions can be resource hogs.  I use a 240 minute idle timeout for a similar issue (not a login but a form that needs to stay open until certain real world tasks are done), but I don't have a lot of traffic  (intranet).

It's pretty odd behavior for a user to sit at the login prompt for 20 minutes without logging in.  You might just notify the user that they must login within 20 minutes or they need to refresh.  You might also use that old redirect header with a 20 minute timeout... just redirect them to a "Login page has timed out" page: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp

Yeah, I think you are right.  It's not a common behavior for a user to sit at the logon page for more than 20 minutes.  I thought ASP.NET CORE would have a solution for such a workflow that our team didn't know about.  I appreciate your feedback and comments to our posting!

You can also set the timeout to 0, which would mean it would never go idle.  Maybe check this thread for possible side effects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330837/setting-application-pool-idletimeout-to-0-side-effects

when you think about it, this setting really only effects sites with low amount of traffic, since it's a timeout for ALL connections, not a single one.  Only if zero connections had been made in that time would the app pool shut down/recycle.
